# NSIS - How to include all folders from source to Installer

Tags: windows, include, installation, nsis, directory

I have an application which consists one `.exe`, many `.dlls`  and a few folders.

I use NSIS to create an installer. It works but when I install the software, I don't see all the folders inside my application.
What do I have to do  to bundle all the folders within my application into the installer?

This is the code I set the data source at this time:

```
File "c:\MyProject\MyApp\*"
```

Answer (score 61):

The documentation tells us that the /r argument of the File command includes all sub folders and files. So you would use something like this:

```
File /r "c:\MyProject\MyApp\*"
```

The relevant section of the documentation can be found here:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#file

Comment: When using the /r switch, both matching directories and files will be searched. *This is always done with or without the use of wildcards*.  http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#file

Comment: Won't this cause problems with an uninstaller? As you can't delete * as you need to wait for uninstaller.exe to be last?